# In Web 8 Delivery, What is the best location to for CD XML's like cd_storage_conf

Tags: content-delivery, discovery-service, microservices

In Web 8 Delivery, What is the best location for CD XML's like cd_storage_conf.xml we should be using in delivery application so that we will nor miss service configurations? While we are configuring services we are giving "localhost" for content service and context service. While we configure in application we should be using Correct DNS entry so that we can access or local host will be okay?

Comment: DNS entry and location of the config files are totally different issues here. Your config can live anywhere as long as the folder have the right permission and config are referencing the right path inside. There is no best location, but usually you shouldn't install this on the root drive

Comment: Thank you robert, 2 things I am looking 1. Consider I am creating DD4T Application in bin folder we should copy cd_storage_conf and other files, from where should i get these files so that i will have all configured services included which will save time to configure individual service. 2.In Storage conf we are adding discovery service URL as "localhost:port\discovery.svc"  If we give local host, how content service can be connected from presentation server?

Comment: if it's an "All-in-one" server then you can use localhost, otherwise you will need to access it via IP or DNS entry that's accessible by the presentation server. To answer your first question, you should read the online doc, it'll tell you what to do

Comment: Just make sure your Discovery service point to the actual path ( https://localhost/discovery.svc ) where you can access it and it should be configured in your Pres server client_config_conf.xml. Your cd_storage_conf.xml is part of your micro services and Deployer now, so if that also is in the same server as Pres then make sure your cd_storage_conf.xml is in root/config folder of your Deployer and Micro services.